# Javascript Coding / Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I want a small image view of a map detailing the Downtown Chicago.
You can just easily say if I have to pay for it. It's a yes or no question.

I'm on a free trial in the Google Cloud. It's simple, do I or do I not, have to pay for the map and the coding?

Can someone possibly answer my question directly?

No more of the run-around with links to API...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Standard plan Google Maps API free of charge if you are OK with the usage limits for the Standard plan. Otherwise, you should enable billing on your project and pay everything that is over the free quota.

Please read the following document to get more details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_apis